# Unable to generate ecdsa-sk key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, git

Suddenly ssh stopeed working on my Ubuntu 20.04 installation. My openssh installation is: OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021

When I execute the ssh command to connect to a remote machine it prompts:

```
...
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_ecdsa ECDSA SHA256:k9vZVEz605zKffb1cHPfjOQ12AtpBHbnWOGnOudqghY agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:bcigijI079uwOJXihyXOFq+sNwzJFYO+T9N2wCVhCIc agent
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Trying private key: /home/angela/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
angela@...: Permission denied (publickey).
```

And when I try to generate id_ecdsa_sk:

```
~/openssh/bin/ssh-keygen -vvvv -t ecdsa-sk
Generating public/private ecdsa-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
debug3: start_helper: started pid=173933
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: start_helper: starting /home/angela/openssh/libexec/ssh-sk-helper 
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal", device "(null)", application "ssh:", userid "(null)", flags 0x01, challenge len 0
debug1: sshsk_enroll: using random challenge
debug1: pick_first_device: fido_dev_info_manifest bad len 0
debug1: ssh_sk_enroll: pick_first_device failed
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal" returned failure -4
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Enrollment failed: device not found
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -60
debug3: reap_helper: pid=173933
Key enrollment failed: device not found
```

I have tried to reinstall openssh through brew but nothing changed, could someone point me the right direction to fix this? Thank you.